# Why are x = x + y and x = y + x different sometimes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can someone please explain how this code works?

```
def reverse(text):
    output = ""
    for letter in text:
        output = letter + output
    return output
print reverse("abcdef")
```

And why using "output = output + letter" does not work?

Comment: Your code is working for me, what's going wrong for you?

Comment: I think you need to do a dry run of your code. It won't take you more than few minutes.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` operator is implemented for `str` to mean *concatenation*. So what does concatenation mean? It means put the second one at the *back* of the first one.

```
"a" + "b" # "ab"
"b" + "a" # "ba"
```

Anyway, if you want to reverse a `str` use the following, it's **efficient** for a number of reasons.

```
output = "".join(reversed(text))
```

Well, as @TigerhawkT3 pointed out you could use much, much faster,

```
output = text[::-1]
```

Comment: `text[::-1]` is probably better.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 yes it's much faster than my solution. Well if you want more control you could put in more functions as a pipeline and it will still be efficient as long as they are all dealing with iterators.

Comment: I wasn't really thinking about speed - `text[::-1]` is shorter, more readable, and pretty much canonical.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Agreed. It's just that I am very much into data pipelines these days. So, you know..

Answer (score 0):

When you use + to join two strings, the order matters: `'A' + 'B'` will give you `'AB'` while  `'B' + 'A'` will give you `'BA'`.  So in your function, each time you do:

```
output = letter + output
```

it's taking the new letter, and adding the string of previous letters to the right of it.  (If you did output = output + letter, you'd just be adding the new letter to the right of the previous letters, which would result in the same exact string that you started with.)